# Detecting columns containing any value quickly with grep

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have a large dataset, 5000 variables and 3 million rows. I want to check what columns contain dates. I'm working with *data.table* and reading the data with `fread`. In order to know what columns contain dates I run this:

```
my[, lapply(.SD,function(xx) 
  length(grep("^\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d{4}$",xx))>0 ) ]
```

or the same with `any(grepl())`

But it's very slow.

Is there any way to do it faster?  Maybe forcing `grep` to stop the first time it encounters a date? I think (command line) grep has an option to do it:

```
grep -m 1
```

But I think it's not available in R.

Any idea? Solutions with base R or other packages are also welcome.

I could also work only with a few rows of the data.table but some columns could have very little values different than NA and there are chances of missing them.

Very simple example with some NA:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
siz <- 10000000
my <- data.table(
  AA=c(rep(NA,siz-1),"11/11/2001"),
  BB=sample(c("wrong", "11/11/2001"),siz, prob=c(1000000,1), replace=T),
  CC=sample(siz),
  DD=rep("11/11/2001",siz),
  EE=rep("HELLO", siz)
 )
```

I've seen there is an option *perl = FALSE* but I don't know wheter it will allow me to add extra parameters.

Or similarly I want to know among the files supposed to be dates whether there are strange symbols. I could run grep on every column but it would be great to be able to stop as soon as my test is right, without continuing till the end of the column.

Maybe with some extra package such as *stringi*?

Comment: I think you may want to generate some example data illustrating the NA problem.

Comment: @Frank I've added it.

Comment: I've added a request at R-development to ask for the -m feature for grep.  But I guess it will take years.

Comment: I've tried with stri_detect_regex from the package stringi, but it's slower.  I expected it to have the option to search for any occurency on a vector and then stop the process, but it doesn't have that option either.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to check only the first row (assuming that if there is a 'Date' class it would pick it up unless the first one is a missing value)

```
my[1][, grepl("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", unlist(.SD))]
```

In addition to the above, as @Frank mentioned we can check only a subset of `character` class columns instead of the whole columns by specifying the `.SDcols`

```
j1 <- sapply(my, is.character)
my[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
            length(grep("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", x))>1), 
              .SDcols = j1]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.table(col1 = rnorm(1e6), col2 = "05/05/1942", 
      col3 = rnorm(1e6))

system.time(res <- dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
                length(grep("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", x))>1)])
# user  system elapsed 
#  6.33    0.01    6.35 

system.time(res2 <- dat[1][, grepl("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", unlist(.SD))])
#   user  system elapsed 
#     0       0       0 


system.time({
  j1 <- sapply(dat, is.character)
  res3 <- dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     length(grep("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", x))>1), .SDcols = j1]
  res3 <- names(dat) %in% names(res3)
     })
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.43    0.00    0.44 



all.equal(unlist(res), res2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(unlist(res), res3, check.attributes=FALSE) 
#[1] TRUE
```

If there are lots of NAs, then we can check on the first row where it has all non-NA elements

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.table(col1 = sample(c(NA, 1:10), 1e6, replace=TRUE),
     col2 = c(NA, "05/05/1942"),
     col3 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e6, replace=TRUE))
dt1 <- head(dat, 20)
#Or just a sample of 20 rows from the dataset
#dt1 <- dat[sample(1:.N, 20, replace=TRUE)]
dt1[dt1[, which(!Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, is.na)))[1]]
     ][,  grepl("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}", unlist(.SD))]
```

Comment: Could maybe also set `.SDcols = sapply(dat, is.character)` since fread also tries to identify numeric, integer, etc. (so it won't generally be the case that every col is character, I mean).

Comment: As I said, quite often the first row (and sometimes most of the rows) contains an NA.
Hal of the columns are character (and most of them will be dates).

Comment: I want to detect column dates in this way, and I'll convert them to posixct later.

Comment: @skan Then check for a couple of rows where all the elements are non-NAs and do this on the first row

Comment: @skan A variation on this answer `patt = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";
system.time(
    sapply(my, function(x) is.character(x) && length(grep(patt, unique(na.omit(x)))) )
)` takes under a second on my computer for your example. Not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: OK, your way is very fast if there are NA, but I just got the real database, dirty, and sometimes the NAs are not NA but any other text. I'm transforming it.

Comment: @skan Well, it's starting to sound like a specific problem that only you can deal with, but you could try extending your example or posting a new question if you think someone can be of more help.

Comment: @skan Okay, I'm seeing the same timing. And if I take out na.omit, it's a bit faster.

Comment: @skan Using Frank's method i get `user  system elapsed 
   0.61    0.29    0.89` for your new dataset.

Comment: @skan Because then the regex test is only applied to unique values. Because you are looking at dates, presumably not spanning more than 100 years, I'd expect you to have fewer than 30k unique values, which makes for a far shorter vector than your original 10 million

Comment: @Frank , if you convert your reply into an answer I will choose it.  the na.omit and unique tricks are very good.   Anyway this doesn't solve my initial doubt on how to force grep to stop when it finds the first occurrency.  (something like grep -m 1).  I guess forcing  R to use an external grep it's going to be slower.

Comment: @skan I think the pattern is the main thing which is why I commented here. If akrun or someone else wants to edit it into his answer, it's fine by me. You could leave the question open and see if someone comes up with something closer to your command line call.